# MySQL Relating Tags

Tags: discussion, tags

I have an urge today to view some questions under the `tag` of my favorite rdbms: [mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql). Upon checking, I've manage to go to its tag info tab and saw its relating tags. Do we really need to create tags specifically designed for [mysql-real-escape-string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql-real-escape-string) and [mysql-error-xxx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql-error-xxx)? I think these tags can be changed to the general [mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql) tag- or am I missing a point?

Comment: Tags are there to help people find things more easily; how does removing these tags achieve that?

Comment: @Ben I'm missing a point perhaps... so if that's the case, then all major `mysql` `php` functions and `mysql-error-xxx` should be tagged.