# MySQL error code tags

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request

I came across a question tagged [mysql-error-1630](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql-error-1630) and was a little appalled to find [61 such tags](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/723176/useless-tags). This seems like a useless set of tags; any error message should be included in the question, and I have been told that **"tags should help describe what the question is about, not just what it contains."**

In addition, many users type "mysql-error" into the tag field and pick the first thing they see. So [mysql-error-1064](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql-error-1064) has >1400 entries, many of which aren't even related to that error code.

I know [this was discussed previously](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274616/do-we-really-need-a-tag-for-every-error-code) and nothing was done (despite +45/-8 on the original question) but I'd like to think that the site has evolved somewhat from 10 years ago. These tags just feel like noise to me. Can we make them all synonyms of [mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql)?

Comment: Instead of making them synonyms I think all the error tags should be burninated.

Comment: related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297588/mysql-relating-tags and one addressing the bigger picture: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274616/do-we-really-need-a-tag-for-every-error-code

Comment: @NathanOliver Does burninating them prevent them from being used in the future? I know synonymizing and merging them does, which is why I suggested it.

Comment: @miken32 No but if they come back we can blacklist them.  To me it just seems weird having [mysql-error-1630] a synonym of [mysql]

Comment: Yes, burninating it seems appropriate. Else we might need to add all other possible MySQL errors so it doesn't feel alone. Having tags or synonyms for specific errors in a specific database is unwanted

Comment: me: "62 questions doesn't seem like that many to clean up." *clicks link* "OMFG you really did mean 62 *tags*!"

Comment: [ mysql-error- ] too many tags

Comment: I don't see any reason to burninate these. That's done when we want to clean up the questions because many of them are low quality or off-topic. Is that the case here? If not, a moderator can just merge and then remove the tags. Simple.

Comment: What we want is those tag to not exist anymore @CodyGray. Burnination implies exactly that. We just take the opportunity to also clean up posts, but it's not strictly necessary. Removing misspelled tags and burnination are the same thing: make the tag go puff.

Comment: No, they are not. But the confusion surrounding this is why I think it's time to retire the term "burninate", because nobody seems to understand exactly what it means. As I already said, there is a much easier way for the tags to be eliminated. I don't know how I could possibly make it any more clear than the previous comment.

Comment: Most of those were added by user [OMG Ponies](https://stackoverflow.com/users/135152/omg-ponies) (no longer active apparently) here's a 7 year old QA discussing the same thing. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274620/73226. Looks like the `ora-00` prefixed tags have survived too.

Comment: @CodyGray "Requests to have a tag **"burninated" (or deleted)** from the system" It means exactly what it does: tag deletion.

Comment: The question is whether those questions are all ontopic. For example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41185551/generate-error-on-mysql-5-7-1025-error-on-rename-column) is obviously off-topic

Comment: @CodyGray "a moderator can just merge and then remove the tags..." Was that an offer?

Comment: Well, yeah, except I'm not seeing consensus. The answer Martin linked, by [OMG Ponies](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274620) has about the same amount of support as this question, in the opposite direction. I don't have a personal stake in or knowledge about these tags, but in general, I like having tags for specific errors, so I'm reluctant to support simply obliterating them.

Comment: +1 to burninating "burninate". We hate fun, and this term is cute but unclear.

Comment: @CodyGray just edited this question with another compelling (?) reason to get rid of these tags. Maybe worth another look?